# SQL Server: Selection based on Rank and Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am finding it difficult to create a rules engine in SQL server where my output is based on 2 inputs.

1. The Ranking of an activity
2. The Points I can earn for each of the Activities

The table contains how many points the individual has earned for each activity as well as the potential points he can still earn.

Each individual is required to earn a certain number of points - for the example shown, the individual needs to earn **80** points to qualify.

The final output must output 3 recommended activities **although** the 3 outputs must take into consideration

1. highest ranked  activity
2. points potential
3. after I total the points on the 3 activities it must be more or greater than **80** to qualify.

I hope this makes sense, will appreciate an assistance here.

Regards

The attached image is an example of the dataset for just 1 staff member, the dataset contains multiple staff members with different points earned per activity.

[image: Points Example]

Comment: What is the desired result? I'm not quite following the business logic.

Comment: Referencing the example.
Total points earned = 80
To qualify, 80 more points are required by completing 1 of the activities.
The desired output must provide recommendation on which of the 3 activities he will have to complete to make up the additional 80 points.
The points potential field will indicate what he can earn this from but, I only want to output 3 of them based on the highest ranked activities as well as to ensure the 3 activities will give him the 80 points or more to qualify.

In this example, output will be as follows:

Activity 1,2 & 4
90 points

The query needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear what you're after but I'm going to guess that you want the 3 activities with the lowest possible ranks (no repeats) that will get the total earned points + potential points above 160. Otherwise it's not clear how you're getting your required points. In this case, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT StaffNumber, Activity1, Activity2, Activity3
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a1.Rank, a2.Rank, a3.Rank) RowNum,
  a.StaffNumber,
  a1.Activity Activity1,
  a2.Activity Activity2,
  a3.Activity Activity3
  FROM (
    SELECT StaffNumber, SUM(PointsEarned) PointsEarnedTotal
    FROM activities
    GROUP BY StaffNumber
  ) a
  INNER JOIN activities a1
    ON a.StaffNumber = a1.StaffNumber
  INNER JOIN activities a2
    ON a.StaffNumber = a2.StaffNumber
    AND a1.Activity <> a2.Activity
  INNER JOIN activities a3
    ON a.StaffNumber = a3.StaffNumber
    AND a1.Activity <> a3.Activity
    AND a2.Activity <> a3.Activity
  WHERE a.PointsEarnedTotal + a1.PointsPotential + a2.PointsPotential + a3.PointsPotential >= 160
) a
where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked out perfectly. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @Nitesh_R in that case, would you be so kind as to accept my answer? :) Thank you.